# Gurobi using Python: Model On/Off Status of Generators

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to model power output of a diesel generator in Gurobi. The generator has the following characteristics:

OFF: No power output, and zero fuel consumption.
ON: Power output must be between 30% and 90% of capacity (e.g., if the generator has a maximum output of 100kW, it can only output between 30kW and 90kW when turned on). Fuel consumption based on a quadratic approximation using power output.

It is trying to meet a load for 24 hours. But there are also other components involved, so it doesn't always need to be on. Actually, I know it would be economically beneficial for it to not always be on. I've tried adding relevant variables to allow it to turn off, but it still chooses to continuously operate, at minimum output for most of the time horizon.

Hoping someone could clue me in on how to better model this so it actually turns off when beneficial. The objective is to minimize cost which is related to fuel consumption.

Comment: I suppose the first constraint is to satisfy the power demand. So if other components cannot do it (like solar panels at night), your generator will work regardless of the cost of kwh

Comment: Can you fix the generator to OFF for a single period and see what happens?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on Operations Research Stack Exchange: https://or.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

I can try to partially answer the question.

Define the

- variable of power setpoint p
- Minimum setpoint : P_min
- Maximum setpoint : P_max
- binary variable : z_online

then your constraints are

1. z_online * P_min <= p <= z_online * P_max

then you can set the demand based on the variable p.
E.g. weekly demand could be : p[1:168] >= Your weekly demand